# What are sub-modules in ES6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, design-patterns, module

Suppose I have a ES6 module named `a.js`. `a.js` modules imports `b.js` and `c.js` modules. Similarly `b.js` imports `d.js` and `c.js` imports `e.js`.

Now what I want to know is which ones are sub-modules and super-modules.

I feel `b.js` and `c.js` are sub-modules of `a.js`. But I am not sure. Really confused. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `sub-modules` ?

Comment: `sub-module` is a term often used by programmers. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such concept as submodules in ES6. There is only concept of module. Module is an abstraction for one unit in the program and ES6 introduced new [syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) for that.

The submodule is *convenient* name for the module, which contained by other module. What is important here is that submodule determined by relation called **contains** and not by relation **imports**. In ES6 submodule used as an abstract concept.

In ES6 one file is one module. So let's review following project structure as an example:

```
myapp/
├── index.es6
└── lib
    ├── index.es6
    ├── backend.es6
    └── validator.es6
```

Here you can say, that `myapp` is *root module*. It contains one *submodule*: `lib`. Module `myapp` is defined inside file `index.es6`. Submodule `lib` of `myapp` module (or just module `myapp/lib`) contains two *submodules*: `backend` and `validator`.

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 module context all modules are created equal, that means you group them in your project by means of creating appropriate folder structure. Something like:

```
src/app.js

src/specificModule/specificModuleA.js

src/common/commonModuleB.js
src/common/commonMofuleC.js

...
```

That being said, if you develop using some build tool, in this case I am thinking about [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/), it can extract commonly used functionality into [common module](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#commons-chunk) for you automatically. It does that by analyzing dependency tree of your source files.

But Webpack is quite complex tool, so for now it should be enough just to structure your project sources in the appropriate folder structure.